# How to sandbox (or monitor) a process on OSX

Tags: mac-osx, monitoring, process

I'm running a piece of OCR software [with gui, etc] on OSX that watches a folder and OCRs PDFs that are put in there.  Occasionally the process starts behaving poorly and consumes a huge amount of system memory and CPU, running indefinitely on a particular PDF.

- I'd like to know how to monitor that process to kill it under such circumstances.
- I'd also like to prevent it from bringing the system to a halt, e.g. by sandboxing somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can sandbox an application on OS X with the built in sandbox(7) facility. See the man pages for sandbox(7), sandbox-exec(1) and sandboxd(8). This repository of sandbox scripts may also be useful.

- https://github.com/s7ephen/OSX-Sandbox--Seatbelt--Profiles

OS X 10.7 (Lion) will bring more [application sandboxing features](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#security), as well, but the details on Apple's site are light. I would assume it will be related to the above feature.

Answer (score 0):

Plain ol' `ps` can help with this: we run a process that considers the number of seconds of CPU each process has consumed according to `ps` versus the elapsed wallclock time and alerts a sysadmin to have a look if the ratio is excessive; you could of course tie that to a kill for specific processes if you so choose.

Comment: Jeff - can you elaborate a touch.  Which ps outputs are you using?  What do you define as "excessive"?

Comment: Well, the 'lstart' field will give you a proc's starting date and time in a parseable format, and the 'cputime' field will tell you the number of seconds of cpu time the process has consumed since it started. Convert current date/time and proc start date/time to epoch seconds, subtract to get the proc's total running seconds, then get the ratio of cpu seconds to running seconds.

Comment: What threshold is appropriate depends on your system and running processes; we alert by default when any process has used 300s of CPU time in 900s of wallclock, and then tune that figure based on a system's typical usage.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Do you know of a way in which I can limit a process on OSX to consumption of only a certain amount of resources a priori?

Comment: I don't know an easy way to specify a numeric value for cpu to wallclock time ratio; the 'nice' family of commands will allow you to specify a process's CPU scheduling priority, which might be what you're looking for (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/renice.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

to kill process you need to find its process number.

```
$ ps a| grep _process_name_
```

this results in list:

Sample:

```
$ ps a|grep Safari
31755 s000  R+     0:00.00 grep Safari
```

now kill the process:

```
kill 31755
```

There are some switches for kill command, sometimes you need to use 
`kill -kill _process number_`

To get a full list of options use `main kill`